# delete multiple users

Tags: awk, last

I am the root user and I am setting up a menu for another user to use. This other user will only get this menu.

There are two options that are interlinked: the first option is to search users. The code I got is:

```
last | awk '{print $1,$4,$5,$6,$7} '
```

I have checked this code and it works, it shows me the usernames and the day they last logged on.

For the second option: I want to be able to set a date, and them delete users who haven't been active since that date, using the output of the above command.

I am using Linux Mint and Vim text editor.

Comment: A question—i.e. a sentence with a question mark (`?`)—would greatly help to indicate what you try to ask.

Comment: i want to know a way to delete multiple users who haven't logged in for a long period of time

Comment: correction i want to enter a date then delete users who have been inactive since that date

Comment: In most states, deleting users is illegal, but deleting there accounts is OK. Secondly deleting accounts may also be problematic. Disabling them may be better. As any leftover resources, may get allocated to a new user.

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers.

Comment: `last` shows login events. It does not show activity. I may have logged in a month ago and stayed logged in while being very active. In this case, `last` may not even show my login event at all (depending on how long the entries in the wtmp database is kept for).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
root@host# lastlog -b Num_Days_Since_Last_Login | egrep -v "^Username|Never logged in" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -i userdel {}
```

Where Num_Days_Since_Last_Login is an integer number of days since last login...

Answer (score 0):

A complete solution :

```
#!/bin/bash

maxdate=$(date -d "$1" +%s) || exit 1
daysdate=$((($(date +%s)-maxdate)/(3600*24)))

LANG=C lastlog -b $daysdate -u 1000- |
    awk 'NR>1{print $1}' |
    xargs -n1 echo userdel
```

Test it and remove `echo` to do it forReal™.
Example usage :

```
./script.sh 'Fri Dec  5 17:00:06 CET 2013'
```